# Is $B_t + B_{2t}$ a Markov process?

Tags: brownian-motion, markov-process

If $B = (B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a standard brownian motion, is $B_t + B_{2t}$ a markov process?

My intuition tells me that it's not a markov process because we don't have independent increments (I think). As far as I know, if we take $t_{k} < t_{k+1} < t_{n} < t_{n+1}$, then nothing assures that $[t_{2(n+1)}, t_{2n}]\cap[t_{2{k+1}}, t_{2k}] = \emptyset$. However, I'm not sure whether this is enough or not. Any help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right because the increments are not independent. You can explicitly compute the covariance of the increments. For example for the increments between $t=0$ to $t=1$ and  between $t=1$ to $t=2$. Assuming $B_0=0$, we compute:
\begin{align}
C_t &= B_t + B_{2t} \\
\mathrm{Cov}(C_1-C_0, C_2-C_1)
&= \mathrm{Cov}(B_1+B_{0.5}, (B_2+B_1)-(B_1+B_{0.5})) \\
&= \mathrm{Cov}(B_1+B_{0.5}, B_2-B_{0.5}) \\
&= \mathrm{Cov}(B_1,B_2)+\mathrm{Cov}(B_{0.5}, B_2)-\mathrm{Cov}(B_1,B_{0.5})-\mathrm{Cov}(B_{0.5},B_{0.5}) \\
&= \mathrm{Cov}(B_1,B_1)+\mathrm{Cov}(B_{0.5}, B_{0.5})-\mathrm{Cov}(B_{0.5},B_{0.5})-\mathrm{Cov}(B_{0.5},B_{0.5}) \\
&= \mathrm{Cov}(B_1,B_1)-\mathrm{Cov}(B_{0.5}, B_{0.5}) \\
&=1-0.5\neq 0
\end{align}
Well, not the most beautiful calculation, but it works. In particular we used the fact that $\mathrm{Cov}(B_a,B_b)=\mathrm{Cov}(B_c,B_c)$ with $c=\min(a,b)$. (This is true because $B$ has independent increments.)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much!

Comment: On more question I've been thinking of: Haven't I to do more things to check that is or is not a markov process? Not independent increments is not enough, isn't it?

Comment: well, in order to prove that it is Markov you have to check more stuff, yes. But in order to disprove Markov it is enough to show that one property is violated. Honestly, I am not completely sure how you would interpret this thing as a Markov process at all. The Markov chains I know have either discrete time, or discrete values (or both, which is the basic case). But here both $t$ and $B_t$ are real numbers, i.e. not discrete values. I am not completely sure how you would define such a process^^